# finding inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

This is from my textbook:

[image]

I don't know how to tell whether the spanning set are actually orthogonal. The textbook's solution is like this, forexample, to see if $P_0(t)$ and $P_1(t)$ are orthognal, it would be $<P_0,P_1>=P_0(-2)P_1(-2)+P_0(-1)P_1(-1)+P_0(0)P_1(0)+P_0(1)P_1(1)+P_0(2)P_1(2)=0$, but isn't $P_0(t)=1$, $P_1(t)=t$ and $P_2(t)=t^2-2$? So it would be like to check sets in $\{1,t,t^2-2\}$ to see if they are orthogonal? that's very confusing.

Comment: To see if the set is orthogonal, take any two (distinct) elements of it, compute their inner product, and check whether it is zero. This is no different than with vectors. Perhaps what is confusing you is that it is not really, say, $1$ (which we think of as a number) which is a vector, it is the *function* $P_0$ defined by $P_0(t)=1$ which we think of as a vector.

Comment: @Ian but how can check <1,t> =0?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check whether $ \left\{ p_0,p_1,p_2 \right\}$ are orthogonal - you are already told they are. To find the best approximation you need to use the Gram-Schmidt process, which builds up this approximation by calculating the projection of $p$ on the subspace $\operatorname{Span} \left\{ p_0,p_1,p_2 \right\}$.

In order to calculate, say, $\left\langle p,p_2 \right\rangle$, simply use the formula you were given:

$$ \left\langle p,p_2 \right\rangle =p(-2)p_2(-2)+p(-1)p_2(-1)+p(0)p_2(0)+p(1)p_2(1)+p(2)p_2(2).$$

In order to calculate each factor of each summand, you need to simply *substitute* the corresponding point into the polynomial. For instance,
$$p(-2)=5-\frac 12 (\color{#C00}{-2})^4,\;p_2(1)=(\color{#C00}{1})^2-2.$$

Comment: but how can check <1,t> =0?

Comment: @whoisit use the formula you were given, like I showed, and *substitute* into the polynomial $t$ the value of a different point each time.